# populating an input list to a service, with console application client

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I'm new to WCF and C#.
I'm using VS 2010.
I'm trying to implement a service that takes a list of strings as input, processes the list and returns another list based on the input list.
**when I try to read the Input list in the command line client I get empty items (nulls) in the list.**

my input data looks like this :

```
<RequestData>
   <IDs>
     <ID>2362</ID>
     <ID>1234</ID>
     <ID>6789</ID>
   </IDs>
</RequestData>
```

my RequestData definition is :

```
namespace RestService
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.myNameSpace.co.il/REST")]
     public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<ID> IDs = new List<ID>();
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.myNameSpace.co.il/REST")]
    public class ID
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the generated proxy code is :

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="RequestData", Namespace="http://www.myNameSpace.co.il/REST")]
public partial class RequestData : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private www.myNameSpace.co.il.REST.ID[] IDsField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public www.myNameSpace.co.il.REST.ID[] IDs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IDsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.IDsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

client code :

```
RequestData req = new RequestData();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(req.GetType());
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(".\\..\\..\\PostData.xml"))
            {
                req = (RequestData) serializer.Deserialize(sr);
            }

            ResponseData res = (ResponseData)client.Enrich(req);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error message is : {0} ", ex.Message);
        }
```

please help, any directions are welcome.

thnx

Comment: Maybe `<ID><item>2362</item></ID>`

Answer (score 0):

It works now, thank you Hogan

I was missing *item*  */item* around my data in the input XML file.

```
<RequestData>
   <IDs>
     <ID><item>2362</item></ID>
     <ID><item>1234</item></ID>
     <ID><item>6789</item></ID>
   </IDs>
</RequestData>
```